# Tags [jquery-event-binding] and [jquery-events] should be merged

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I think [jquery-event-binding](/questions/tagged/jquery-event-binding) and [jquery-events](/questions/tagged/jquery-events) should be merged. They have a similar meaning and the questions used by each tag are the same, as the tags are not always correctly used.

Comment: Well, similar != exact.

Comment: On Meta, downvotes mean the users don't agree with you (unlike the main site where they often mean the question is poorly researched).

Comment: @Undo No it does not. However, the way they are used on the site, are exact.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be several jquery events not related to binding: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp

Here's an example of a SO jquery question that doesn't have to do with binding: [Does setting jQuery.data() trigger an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528284/does-setting-jquery-data-trigger-an-event)

Comment: The events are only used to bind the events, whether you're using `.on`, `.click`/`.mouseover`/etc., etc.

Comment: If you have a question about an event, it's not always going to specifically be about BINDING the event.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I can see that custom events wouldn't fall under binding, but [tag:jquery-events] is being used anyway, so there's no separation in questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528284/does-setting-jquery-data-trigger-an-event

Comment: If you edit your answer, I can remove the downvote. However, being that questions that, in your case, should only use [tag:jquery-event-binding] are mostly using [tag:jquery-events], I still believe that the tags should be merged.

Comment: I don't think they have same meaning, but given how they seem to be used now merge makes sense - now there is no added value in them separate anyway, even if there should be some.